# The Number of Rows with a Specific Number of Missing Values

Tags: r

Imagine a small data set like the one below, composed of three variables:

```
 v1 <- c(0, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0)
 v2 <- c(0, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA)
 v3 <- c(1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0)
 df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)

 df
   v1 v2 v3
 1  0  0  1
 2  1  0 NA
 3 NA NA  0
 4  1  1  0
 5 NA NA NA
 6  0 NA  0
```

One can use the is.na command as follows to calculate the number of rows with at least one missing value - and R would return 4:

```
sum(is.na(df$v1) | is.na(df$v2) | is.na(df$v3))
```

Or the number of rows with all three values missing - and R would return 1:

```
sum(is.na(df$v1) & is.na(df$v2) & is.na(df$v3))
```

Two questions at this point:

(1) How can I calculate the number of rows where "exactly one" or "exactly two" values are missing?

(2) If I am to do the above in a large data set, how can I limit the scope of the calculation to v1, v2 and v3 (that is, without having to create a subset)?

I tried variations of is.na, nrow and df, but could not get any of them to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowSums` on the logical matrix (`is.na(df)`) and check whether the number of NAs are equal to the value of interest.

```
n1 <- 1
sum(rowSums(is.na(df))==n1)
```

To make it easier, create a function to do this

```
f1 <- function(dat, n){
          sum(rowSums(is.na(dat)) == n)
        }


f1(df, 0)
#[1] 2
f1(df, 1)
#[1] 2

f1(df, 3)
#[1] 1
f1(df, 2)
#[1] 1
```

NOTE: `rowSums` is very fast, but if it is a large dataset, then creating a logical matrix can also create problems in memory.  So, we can use `Reduce` after looping through the columns of the dataset (`lapply(df, is.na)`).

```
sum(Reduce(`+`, lapply(df, is.na))==1)
#[1] 2

f2 <- function(dat, n){
      sum(Reduce(`+`, lapply(dat, is.na))==n)
 }

f2(df, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
num.rows.with.x.NA <- function(df, x, cols=names(df)) {
   return(sum(apply(df, 1, function(y) sum(is.na(y[cols])) == x)))
}

df

  v1 v2 v3
1  0  0  1
2  1  0 NA
3 NA NA  0
4  1  1  0
5 NA NA NA
6  0 NA  0

num.rows.with.x.NA(df, 0, names(df))
#[1] 2
num.rows.with.x.NA(df, 1, names(df))
#[1] 2
num.rows.with.x.NA(df, 2, names(df))
#[1] 1
num.rows.with.x.NA(df, 3, names(df))
#[1] 1
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel here in inefficient manner. R has all these functions vectorized

Comment: yes, we can use rowSums / Reduce by akrun if efficiency is the concern @David.